# Why Unknown function "getJalse" in factory Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying make an ajax request to php from angular js. But I am not getting the data I have sent by php file.

an error  Unknown function "getJalse" exist in factory

My source:

File app.js:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                controller: 'contentsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/contents.php'
            })

            .when('/jalse/:jalseId', {
                controller: 'recordsCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/jalse.php'
            })

            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
     });

}());
```

File jalseFactory.js:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

var jasleFactory = function ($http, $q) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.getJalses = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/records.php'}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return factory;
};

jasleFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
angular.module('myApp').factory('jasleFactory', jasleFactory);

}());
```

File recordsCtrl.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var recordsCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams , jasleFactory) {
    var jalseId = $routeParams.jalseId;

    $scope.records = jasleFactory.getJalse();

    $scope.jalse = null;

    function init() {
        for (var i = 0, len = $scope.records.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ($scope.records[i].contentID == parseInt(jalseId)) {
                $scope.jalse = $scope.records[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    init();

};

recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope' , '$routeParams' , 'jasleFactory'];

angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your factory has getJalses and you are calling getJalse.

Change

```
factory.getJalses = function ()
```

To

```
factory.getJalse = function ()
```

Comment: thankful. I change code:  
solved last error But Error: 
Error: input is undefined